# AngularJs http get response

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, get

This is my HTTP get request

```
 $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: baseURL + '/couponManager/createCoupon?token=' + token + query1 + query2 + query3 + query4 + query5,
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {


                  if (response.status = 200)
                    {
                      $scope.showSuccessAlert = true;
                       $scope.successTextAlert = "Coupon successfully created!";
                    }

                  else if (response.status = 304)
                    { 
                      $scope.errorAlert = true;
                      $scope.errorTextAlert = "Something Went Wrong, Please try again!";
                     }

                }, function errorCallback(response) {

                     $scope.errorAlert = true;
                     $scope.errorTextAlert = "Can't reach server, please try later!";
              });
```

This is the response I get

```
{"success":"no","data":{},"error_code":"DW3","error_description":"Server Error"}
```

But the status i receive is still 200,  how can I retrieve the "error_description" and "status" from this response?

Comment: can you show the `backend` code? it depends what you send the `status` and `response` back from the backend.

Comment: 1) Use the `params` config instead of concatenating query parameters. 2) Your backend should return an actual HTTP error response status code for unsuccessful requests. 3) Comparisons are made with `===` or `==`, not `=`; that is for assignments

Comment: 4) The data you want is actually in `response.data.success`, `response.data.data`, `response.data.error_code`, etc

Comment: can you do `console.log(response)` and show what it looks like?

Comment: @Phil Thank you much! I needed to put checks on response.data.success. That was what I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition `if (response.status == 200)` & `else if (response.status == 304)`

Comment: I have changed it thanks! the problem is get returns 200 even when "success" : "no" . How can I put conditions on this "success" ?

Comment: It is not the reason as to why the status and the response do not match. Its the backend that decides what status and response to send. But you have pointed out a good mistake.

Comment: so you mean the "status = 200" is sent by back end even when "success is no"? because Backend is written by someone else

Comment: yeah, `status=200` means that you are getting a response from the backend successfully. it doesnt say that whether it was success or not

Comment: Yeah, I have to deal with error_codes instead using response.data.error_code
Thanks